# Application cannot be downloaded by Edge since latest big Windows update

Tags: c#, windows, download, manifest

since the last Windows update, I have trouble with my work-application.
The Programm is available only online and worked fine until the last big windows-update. Edge complains about a *non-downloadable manifest*.
If I use the old IE or copy the link to the explorer it works fine, as before.

I tried signing the app with "ClickOnce Manifest", or signing by Assembly but the same error remains.
The manifest-data is always included and even newly created manifest or the embedded manifest gives the same problem.
(it's an app.manifest xml-file)

I'll add the full error-log but its mostly in German.

```
INFO ZUR PLATTFORMVERSION
    Windows             : 10.0.18363.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    clr.dll             : 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfdll.dll           : 4.8.4200.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.18362.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

QUELLEN
    Bereitstellungs-URL         : file:///C:/Users/myself/Downloads/MyProgram%20(11).application

IDENTITÄTEN
    Bereitstellungsidentität        : MyProgram.application, Version=3.0.0.37, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=760019a0718d98b6, processorArchitecture=x86

ZUSAMMENFASSUNG FÜR ANWENDUNG
    * Reine Onlineanwendung.

FEHLERZUSAMMENFASSUNG
    Es folgt eine Zusammenfassung der Fehler. Details zu diesen Fehlern werden später im Protokoll aufgelistet.
    * Die Aktivierung von C:\Users\myself\Downloads\MyProgram (11).application führte zu einer Ausnahme. Folgende Fehlermeldungen wurden entdeckt:
        + 'file:///C:/Users/myself/Downloads/Application Files/MyProgram_3_0_0_37/MyProgram.exe.manifest' konnte nicht gedownloadet werden.
        + Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\myself\Downloads\Application Files\MyProgram_3_0_0_37\MyProgram.exe.manifest" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
        + Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\myself\Downloads\Application Files\MyProgram_3_0_0_37\MyProgram.exe.manifest" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
        + Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\myself\Downloads\Application Files\MyProgram_3_0_0_37\MyProgram.exe.manifest" konnte nicht gefunden werden.

FEHLERZUSAMMENFASSUNG FÜR DIE SPEICHERTRANSAKTION DER KOMPONENTE
    Es wurde kein Transaktionsfehler festgestellt.

WARNUNGEN
    Während dieses Vorgangs gab es keine Warnungen.

FORTSCHRITTSSTATUS DES VORGANGS
    * [28.09.2020 17:09:07] : Die Aktivierung von C:\Users\myself\Downloads\MyProgram (11).application wurde gestartet.
    * [28.09.2020 17:09:07] : Das Verarbeiten des Bereitstellungsmanifestes wurde erfolgreich abgeschlossen.
    * [28.09.2020 17:09:07] : Die Installation der Anwendung wurde gestartet.

FEHLERDETAILS
    Folgende Fehler wurden bei diesem Vorgang entdeckt.
    * [28.09.2020 17:09:07] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (unbekannter Untertyp)
        - 'file:///C:/Users/myself/Downloads/Application Files/MyProgram_3_0_0_37/MyProgram.exe.manifest' konnte nicht gedownloadet werden.
        - Quelle: System.Deployment
        - Stapelüberwachung:
            bei System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            bei System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
            bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Interne Ausnahme ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\myself\Downloads\Application Files\MyProgram_3_0_0_37\MyProgram.exe.manifest" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
        - Quelle: System
        - Stapelüberwachung:
            bei System.Net.FileWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            bei System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Interne Ausnahme ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\myself\Downloads\Application Files\MyProgram_3_0_0_37\MyProgram.exe.manifest" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
        - Quelle: System
        - Stapelüberwachung:
            bei System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)
            bei System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state)
        --- Interne Ausnahme ---
        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        - Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\myself\Downloads\Application Files\MyProgram_3_0_0_37\MyProgram.exe.manifest" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
        - Quelle: mscorlib
        - Stapelüberwachung:
            bei System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
            bei System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
            bei System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
            bei System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async)
            bei System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint)

DETAILS ZUR SPEICHERTRANSAKTION DER KOMPONENTE
    Es sind keine Transaktionsinformationen verfügbar.
```

Comment: I can't read German, but it looks like you're trying to download via your local files? Is your URL really `file:///C:/Users/myself/Downloads/MyProgram%20(11).application`? Otherwise, can you change the machine's language to English, reproduce the error, then post the English log?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare working and non working code.  Check the version of TLS.  five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1do to security issues.  IN June this year Microsoft pushed a security update that disables TLS 1.0/1.1 on servers and required TLS 1.2/1.3 to be used.  So clients that still used TLS 1.0/1.1 need to be updated to use TLS 1.2/1.3.  The version of TLS being used in clients is a combination of version selected in code, the version of Net, the version of windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try enable `ClickOnce` in EDGE :

```
edge://flags/#edge-click-once -> Enable it
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#clickonceenabled